Do reverts really need to say the shahadah in arabic?
Islamqa.info tells the shahadah can be affirmed in its meaning.
https://www.google.com/amp/s/islamqa.info/amp/en/answers/239026
The following are instances in Quran &  sunni corpus where people attained Islam with a testimony which is different to the standard one.

The magicians of firaun said "We believe in the Rabb of Musa and harun" Quran 20:70

The people of ditch, ashabul aqdood said "We believe in the Rabb of this young man"
[Muslim 3005]

Zaid bin amr bin nufayl said "O Allah bear witness I'm upon the religion of Ibrahim "
[Bukhari 3827]

Waraqah bin nawfal affirmed that the angel which brought revelation to prophet is called namoos and he would support him if he was alive in future [bukhari 3392]


There is ijma that all above became muslims and waraqah became a companion by that statement of his as per some scholarly opinions.
https://islamqa.info/en/answers/182441/was-waraqah-ibn-nawfal-a-companion
Since the magicians of firaun didnt speak Arabic, it can be construed that they said the testimony with a identical wording in a different language.
So the question is can reverts whose language is not Arabic can say something similar to "I believe in deity of muhammad" or "I believe in deity of muslims" to validate to muslims that they follow Islam now?
PS: it will ease difficulty of non Arabic speaking reverts, to say the testimony, since Islam is easy [ bukhari 39]

According to a fatwa from Grand Ayatollah Sayyid Ali al-Sistani A person who wants to convert to the religion of Islam and is unfamiliar with the Arabic language can first tell him the meaning of the sentences of the shahadah in his own language and slowly repeat the words of the shahadah in Arabic so that he repeats them along with the speaker. If he is unable to repeat the Arabic words, he can say the translation of the testimonies in his own language and that is enough.
Reference
